Getting 'System.LimitException: reports:Too many query rows: 50001' in report via apex even when only 20k records are a part of it
I have a batch in which the start method consists of a query with two child queries in it and in the execute method, after some processing the records are made a part of a report. When the number of records in the report is around 20k we get 'System.LimitException: reports:Too many query rows: 50001' error.
Is this a limitation of the Reports API in Apex? or does maximum number of records that can be queried in a transaction has something to do here? and do we have a work around for the same?

This question is similar to: System.LimitException: reports:Too many query rows: 50001. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi Tushar, in the question you mentioned, the author accepts that there are more than 50k records in his report whereas I on the other hand only have 20k records in it still getting the error, that's the difference.

Do you have a class marked Database.Stateful?

Yes, the batch is marked Database.Stateful.

If possible can you please share your code here?
